# Creating a predicate for the following where condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, predicate

I have looked at many posts but unable to find an answer to my question.

I have a lot of queries that are using the Where condition as below. In the code it looks quite ugly, so i thought of using a predicate (dont know whether it is possible or not).

```
.Where(i => i.Timestamp <= date.ToUniversalTime() && i.Timestamp >= yearStart.ToUniversalTime())
```

I want this to become or something like this

```
.WhereYearTotal(date)
```

so the condition can be evaluated within "WhereYearTotal" function.

---

Edited:

I have already tried the extension method but it does not seem to work inside a nested query such as:

```
var query = (from o in db.tableA
        select new {
           monthly =  db.tableA.WhereYearTotal(date),
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get a Null reference exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). I will let you do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using [extension methods.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) You need to create a static class and a static method for it.

```
static class MyHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereYearTotal(this IEnumerable<T> input, DateTime d)
    {
         return input.Where( ... )
    }
}

// usage : (the namespace for MyHelper must be in your using list)
myCollection.WhereYearTotal( DateTime.Now );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own extension method for IQueryable:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereYearTotal<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    DateTime date ) {
    return source.Where(i => i.Timestamp <= date.ToUniversalTime() && i.Timestamp >= yearStart.ToUniversalTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Predicate` is method passed as argument to `Where`. What you want is not a predicate, but [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<MyClass> WhereYearTotal(this IEnuerable<MyClass> source, DateTime date)
        {
            return source.Where(i => i.Timestamp <= date.ToUniversalTime() && i.Timestamp >= yearStart.ToUniversalTime())
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: actually after i posted the question I tried the same way, but there is a problem. I cant use the extension method inside the query such as below: `code` var query = (from o in db.tableA
         select new
              {
               monthly =  db.tableA.WhereYearTotal(date),
              }).FirstOrDefault();